# RegEx with escaped double quotes

Tags: regex

I have the following RegEx that mostly works for my use cases (CLI command interpreter):

```
[^\s"]+|"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"
```

It matches the following scenarios (and separates parts successfully):

```
foo list
foo list --barId ae920cf4-79e7-4c6f-8420-2d64cd6e4ae2
foo list --name "foo's name"
foo create --description "this is a \"description\" with some escaped quotes"
```

The missing piece is where I have escaped double quotes that are not wrapped by outer, un-escaped double quotes. Example:

```
bar create --expression service.GetData(\"2194c75c-26be-405a-b264-5a96152d93f8\")
```

Here, the entire "service.GetData" statement should be a single match, but it breaks at the (escaped) double quote. If I wrap the parameter value in double quotes, it works (as it does in the previous example block). Unfortunately though, I need it to also work when the parameter value is not wrapped in double quotes.

Can someone help with that last piece?

Comment: You have the same start pattern twice: [^\s"]+|[^\s"]+

Comment: copy/paste issue, fixed.

Comment: This looks like a Perl regexp. Is this used in Perl? Use a real tokenizer like Text::Parse's `shellwords()` function. It will handle things like 'single quotes' and backticks and `things" with inline double "quotes`.

Comment: Nope, not Perl. The RegEx is executed in an ASP.NET Core API.

Comment: Surely ASP.NET Core API has functionality to parse command line options, no?  This is no doubt a solved problem in whatever language you're using.

Comment: In this particular app, there are some non-standard and more complex parameter parsing scenarios in place that are not relevant to the question at hand and were therefore excluded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just wrapping all param values with double-quotes from the CLI client application. This made the original RegEx work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use single quotes? As if so then you can put your quote capturing section first so it greedily matches.

`(?:"|')[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*(?:"|')|[^\s"]+`

That will then match the following:

```
bar create --expression 'service.GetData(\"2194c75c-26be-405a-b264-5a96152d93f8\")'
```

Otherwise you have the problem of how do you differentiate between sections. Unless you can make a further constraint upon spacing. If you are able to say that you can't pass spaces in an argument that isn't wrapped in quotes then you can do:

```
"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"|([^\s])+|[^\s"]+
```